# Add an optional fee based on item quantity for different categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, session, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to set custom fees per item in WooCommerce checkout and sum up final price. Items should be from several categories. Fees to be applied on Checkbox click.

Edited some code found here, it works but only adding fees for all items in the cart without conditions per category:

```
// Add a custom checkbox fields after billing fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_custom_checkout_checkbox', 20 );
function add_custom_checkout_checkbox(){

    // Add a custom checkbox field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'installment_fee', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'label' => __(' Faster ship'),
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    ), '' );
}

// Remove "(optional)" label on "Installement checkbox" field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'installment_fee' === $key && is_checkout() ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// jQuery - Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_fee_script' );
function checkout_fee_script() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    if( WC()->session->__isset('enable_fee') )
        WC()->session->__unset('enable_fee')
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=installment_fee]', function(e){
            var fee = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? '1' : '';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'enable_fee',
                    'enable_fee': fee,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_enable_fee', 'get_enable_fee' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_enable_fee', 'get_enable_fee' );
function get_enable_fee() {
    if ( isset($_POST['enable_fee']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('enable_fee', ($_POST['enable_fee'] ? true : false) );
    }
    die();
}

// Add a custom dynamic 3% fee
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_percetage_fee', 20, 1);
function custom_percetage_fee($cart)
{
    // Only on checkout
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) || !is_checkout())
        return;

    // Gets cart contents
    foreach ($cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item) {

        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

        $amount = 5;

        $total_qty = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
    }

    if (WC()->session->get('enable_fee')) {
        $cart->add_fee(__('Make shipping faster', 'woocommerce') . " (5 usd.)", ($quantity * $amount));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear… What categories do you want to handle and how? Try to better explain things, updating your question, and giving all related details and settings.

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your last function, try instead the following (replacing your last function), that handle product categories restrictions:

```php
// Add a custom dynamic item quantity based fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_percetage_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_percetage_fee( $cart ) {
    // Only on checkout
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_checkout() )
        return;
    
    if( WC()->session->get('enable_fee') ) {
        $amount   = 5;
        $quantity = 0;
        $terms    = array('shirts', 'glasses', 'shoes'); // Product category slugs

        // loop through cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( has_term($terms, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) ) {
                $quantity += $cart_item['quantity']; 
            }
        }

        $cart->add_fee(__('Make shipping faster', 'woocommerce').' (5 usd.)', ($quantity * $amount));
    }
}
```

> To handle **Product Tags**, replace in the code `'product_cat'` by `'product_tag'`…

Code goes in function.php file of your  child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.